# How can I write variables names with fopen?

Tags: php

I am trying to write in a configuration file, problem that it does not print `$names`

```
<?php 
    $myfile = fopen("config.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "$dbname = '1'; $dbuser = '2'; $dbpass = '123'; $dbhost = 'localhost';\n"; 
    fwrite($myfile, $txt); 
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

The output shows me

```
= '1';  = '1';  = '123';  = 'localhost';
```

I need he write the variables names, need some help, thanks!

Comment: in double quote strings, variables are replaced by their value, use simple quotes `'` instead

Comment: ...or escape the `$` signs: `\$dbname = '1'; \$dbuser ...`

Comment: use single quote instead of double quote $txt = '$dbname = \'1\'; $dbuser = \'2\'; $dbpass = \'123\'; $dbhost = \'localhost\';";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape $ signs:

```
 $myfile = fopen("config.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
 $txt = " \$dbname = '1'; \$dbuser = '2'; \$dbpass = '123'; \$dbhost = 'localhost';\n"; 
 fwrite($myfile, $txt); fclose($myfile);
```

Other wise use single quotes:

```
 $myfile = fopen("config.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
 $txt = ' $dbname = "1"; $dbuser = "2"; $dbpass = "123"; $dbhost = "localhost";\n'; 
 fwrite($myfile, $txt); fclose($myfile);
```

**Explanation**:

variables $var in php are evaluated if in double quotes, but not in single quotes. I think that for performances it would always be better to avoid double  quotes if the expression inside is constant and doesn't need to be evaluated.